# Adding another row to tableView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

this is my first time asking and i hope you can help me! well, the problem is that i'm doing right now the Big Nerd Ranch iOS guide, i have a challenge where i have to fill a tableview with two sections, 1 for items over 50 dollars, and other for items under 50 dollars. After all the list of items i have to add a cell which specifies that there's No more items to add. Let's say i have 5 items, 2 on the first section and 3 on the other section. Now, i will post the code so you can check it out. The problem i found is numberofRowsInSection i guess and of course that No more items! appears after the end of the last item. Hope you can help me!

```
@interface JDMItemsViewController()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *moreThanFifty;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *lessThanFifty;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *rowsForSections;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *items;
@end

@implementation JDMItemsViewController


-(instancetype)init
{
    //Call the superclass's designated initializer
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            [[JDMItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}

#pragma mark - tableview datasource and delegate methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if ([self.items count] > 0) {
        return [self.rowsForSections count];
    }else {
      return 1;
    }
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *headers = [NSArray array];
    if ([self.items count] == 0) {
        headers = @[@"No items to show"];
        return [headers objectAtIndex:0];
    }else {

    headers = @[@"Items with value above 50",@"Items with value under 50"];
        return [headers objectAtIndex:section];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self.items count] > 0) {
        if (section == 0) {
            self.moreThanFifty = [self overFifty:[[JDMItemStore sharedStore]allItems]];
            return [self.moreThanFifty count] + 1;
        }

        if (section == 1) {
            self.lessThanFifty = [self underFifty:[[JDMItemStore sharedStore]allItems]];
            return [self.lessThanFifty count] + 1;
        }
    }

    return 1;



}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //NSArray *items = [[JDMItemStore sharedStore] allItems];

    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections];

    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;

   __unused NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];

    if ([self.items count] > 0) {

         if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            [self overFifty:self.items];
             if (indexPath.row < [self.moreThanFifty count]) {
                 cell.textLabel.text = [self.moreThanFifty[indexPath.row] description];
             }else {
                  cell.textLabel.text = @"No more Items!";
             }


         }
         if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            [self underFifty:self.items];
             if (indexPath.row < [self.lessThanFifty count]) {
                 cell.textLabel.text = [self.lessThanFifty[indexPath.row] description];
             }else {
                 cell.textLabel.text = @"No more Items!";
             }


        }

    }

    else if([self.items count] == 0)  {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No more Items!";
    }



    return cell;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.items = [[JDMItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    self.moreThanFifty = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.lessThanFifty = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.rowsForSections = @[self.moreThanFifty,self.lessThanFifty];



    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}

#pragma mark - helper methods

-(NSMutableArray *)overFifty:(NSArray *)items
{
    if ([items count] > 0) {
        for (JDMItem * i in items) {
            if (i.valueInDollars >= 50) {
                [self.moreThanFifty addObject:i];
            }
        }

    }

    return self.moreThanFifty;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)underFifty:(NSArray *)items
{
    if ([items count] > 0) {
        for (JDMItem *i in items) {
            if (i.valueInDollars < 50) {
                [self.lessThanFifty addObject:i];
            }

        }
    }

    return  self.lessThanFifty;

}



@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if ([self.items count] > 0) {
        return 2;
    }else {
      return 1;
    }
}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *headers = [NSArray array];
    if ([self.items count] == 0) {
        headers = @[@"No items to show"];
        return [headers objectAtIndex:0];   
    }else {
    headers = @[@"Items with value above 50",@"Items with value under 50"];
        return [headers objectAtIndex:section];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self.items count] > 0) {
        if (section == 0) {
            self.moreThanFifty = [self overFifty:[[JDMItemStore sharedStore]allItems]];
            return [self.moreThanFifty count] + 1;
        }else if (section == 1) {
            self.lessThanFifty = [self underFifty:[[JDMItemStore sharedStore]allItems]];
            return [self.lessThanFifty count] + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //NSArray *items = [[JDMItemStore sharedStore] allItems];

    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections];

    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;

   __unused NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];

    if ([self.items count] > 0) {

         if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            //[self overFifty:self.items];
            if (indexPath.row < [self.moreThanFifty count]) {
                cell.textLabel.text = [self.moreThanFifty[indexPath.row] description];
            }
            else{
                cell.textLabel.text = @"No more Items!";
            }
         }
         else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
             if (indexPath.row < [self.lessThanFifty count]) {
                cell.textLabel.text = [self.lessThanFifty[indexPath.row] description];
             }
             else{
                 cell.textLabel.text = @"No more Items!";
             }
        }

     }
     return cell;
 }
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: please see my comments this is exactly what I suggested to do, thanks for putting all the code. jdecuirm, please could you try this full code and see if the output is what you need? I'm not sure now if this is what you are trying to get.

Comment: @barbaraRodeker >> I think he just put my code in his question. And can you please tell me how it does not answer the question?

Comment: Well if i can upload pictures i would show you! But for the moment it is working!!! Thanks @Rashad and Barbara!!! You are made of gold!

Comment: @barbaraRodeker >> Okay. What does Rodeker means?

Comment: no problem thanks guys, good to know it works now jdecuirm. good night!

Answer (score 0):

I guess for this you don't have to create a new cell at end of each section stating no more items to add. Instead you can use

```
tableView:titleForFooterInSection:
tableView:viewForFooterInSection:
tableView:heightForFooterInSection:
```

methods and render a custom footer your sections which mimic to appear like your table cell.

Comment: Yeah! that was one of my approaches, then i had another challenge where i had to move rows but not under the No more items! cell, so i really had to create that cell! But thanks for the reply and help!!!